# How get data from windows service (that is created by WCF-Communicate with windows service)?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I created a windows service with wcf like this : 
[Microsoft Sample Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

so my question is :

How can I get data from this windows service as client application (for example get some classes or array bytes) ?

Comment: Why don't you read a good book or tutorial on it? This is a Q&A site and explaining WCF is not exactly a simple question. It's way to broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the high level steps:

1. Create a C# Project for the WCF CLient. (can be Console App, Win Forms, Web Application etc.)
2. Right click on **Project References** and **Add Service Reference**.
3. Enter the WCF Service URL, the one used for the Windows Service.
4. Visual Studio will create a proxy class for you along with necessary binding information.
5. With the proxy in place & the Windows Service running, you can use the proxy as follows:

   using (ProxyNamespace.ProxyClass proxy = new ProxyNamespace.ProxyClass())
   {
    var webMethodReturnType = proxy.SomeWebMethod1();
   }